# Replace NA values when they are in two adjacent columns

Tags: r

Hi this is an example of a similar dataframe I am working with. I have an experiment with 10 samples and two replicates

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                "Rep1" =  c(6,5,3,"Na","Na",9,4,"Na","Na",2),
                 "Rep2" = c(8,4,4,"Na",3,"Na",6,"Na",2,1))
```

I have different Na values, however, I only want to replace them with zeros in the samples 4 and 8 due to they are the only ones which have NA in both replicates. Then, other samples would maintain the "NA".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the following solution. In the following solution we iterate over each row and detect corresponding index or indices that is (are) equal to `Na` then if there were more that one index we replace it with `0` otherwise the row will remain as it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  pmap_df(., ~ {ind <- which(c(...) == "Na"); 
  if(length(ind) > 1) {
    replace(c(...), ind, "0")
  } else {
    c(...)
  } 
 }
) %>%
  mutate(across(ID, as.integer))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
      ID Rep1  Rep2 
   <int> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 6     8    
 2     2 5     4    
 3     3 3     4    
 4     4 0     0    
 5     5 Na    3    
 6     6 9     Na   
 7     7 4     6    
 8     8 0     0    
 9     9 Na    2    
10    10 2     1
```

P.S = I almost went crazy as why I could not get it to work only to realize your `NA`s are in fact `Na`.

Answer (score 2):

We create an index where the 'Rep' columns are both "Na" with `rowSums` on a logical matrix.  Use the row, column index/names to subset the data and assign the values to 0

```
nm1 <- grep("Rep", names(df), value = TRUE)
i1 <-  rowSums(df[nm1] == "Na") == length(nm1) 
df[i1, nm1] <- 0
```

-output

```
df
   ID Rep1 Rep2
1   1    6    8
2   2    5    4
3   3    3    4
4   4    0    0
5   5   Na    3
6   6    9   Na
7   7    4    6
8   8    0    0
9   9   Na    2
10 10    2    1
```

---

As the OP created string "Na", the column types are not `numeric`.  We can convert this to numeric as

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.numeric)
```

forces the "Na" to be converted to `NA`

-output

```
df
   ID Rep1 Rep2
1   1    6    8
2   2    5    4
3   3    3    4
4   4    0    0
5   5   NA    3
6   6    9   NA
7   7    4    6
8   8    0    0
9   9   NA    2
10 10    2    1
```

Comment: This is great, however, I still have a question. Is it possible to do it without the manually created index? As I said this is an example, I have about 2,000 samples and is not possible to apply it like this.

So, is it possible to program how to create the index?

Thanks!

Comment: @RafaelBravo sorry, i missed the logic you mentioned. Can you try now

Comment: Yes, the point is that my actual dataframe has ~ 2,000 samples. So the difficult thing now is creating the index for that huge sample.

Comment: @RafaelBravo I updatd the post. It should work now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` we could:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Rep"), ~case_when(.=="Na" & ID==4 | ID==8 ~ "0",
                                               TRUE ~ .)))
```

Output:

```
   ID Rep1 Rep2
1   1    6    8
2   2    5    4
3   3    3    4
4   4    0    0
5   5   Na    3
6   6    9   Na
7   7    4    6
8   8    0    0
9   9   Na    2
10 10    2    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it has been marked as solved, yet I propose a simple answer

```r
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 "Rep1" =  c(6,5,3,"Na","Na",9,4,"Na","Na",2),
                 "Rep2" = c(8,4,4,"Na",3,"Na",6,"Na",2,1))
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(replace(cur_data(), all(cur_data() == 'Na'), '0'))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [10]
#>       ID Rep1  Rep2 
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#>  1     1 6     8    
#>  2     2 5     4    
#>  3     3 3     4    
#>  4     4 0     0    
#>  5     5 Na    3    
#>  6     6 9     Na   
#>  7     7 4     6    
#>  8     8 0     0    
#>  9     9 Na    2    
#> 10    10 2     1
```

---

OR

```
df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(replace(cur_data()[-1], all(cur_data()[-1] == 'Na'), '0'))
```